# Issue With Pulling Remote XML Data into Oracle Database

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, stored-procedures

In an Oracle database, I am reading some XML from a RESTful web service that looks like this:

```
<ns1:parent xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/xml" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xs1:schemaLocation= "http://www.example.com/xml http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns1:child>
      <ns1:options></ns1:options>
      <ns1:variables></ns1:variables>
      <ns1:values>
        <ns1:value qualifiers="X" date="someTime">Value1</ns1:value>
        <ns1:value qualifiers="X" date="someOtherTime">Value2</ns1:value>
        ...
        <ns1:value qualifiers="X" date="some100thTime">Value100</ns1:value>
      </ns1:values>
    </ns1:child>
```

I am then trying to take this data and extract it into the database using the code below. However, when I do so it creates one record with only the SYSDATE field and the other two values are blank.  I also attempted this with XMLTable, but that had the same result.  I'm thinking there's an issue with the namespace, but I can't find the proper syntax and all other combinations that I've tried don't return any rows at all.

We also pull data from another, almost identical data source that does not use namespaces, and this code works fine (without all of the namespaces, of course).  Am I getting the syntax of the namespaces wrong somewhere?

```
DECLARE
myXMLType XMLType := xmltype(We use a function to pull in the XML file here);
BEGIN
/*Outputting the XMLType here shows that data is in it*/
INSERT INTO output_table 
  SELECT 
    ExtractValue(VALUE(p), '/values/ns1:value', 
        'xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/xml"') AS myValue,
    ExtractValue(VALUE(p), '//values/ns1:value/@ns1:date', 
        'xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/xml"') AS myTime,
    SYSDATE AS read_date
  FROM 
    TABLE(XMLSequence(EXTRACT(myXMLType, '/ns1:parent/ns1:child/ns1:values', 
        'xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/xml"')))p;
  COMMIT; 
END;
```

Comment: Please edit XML sample to show complete, valid example.

Comment: I'm not sure what else needs to be added, that's pretty much the whole file with exception of two other tags listed under ns1:child. I have added them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an XMLTable for this as you thought, but you need to [supply an XMLNameSpaces clause too](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5097). This is using a bind variable called `string` which holds your XML text (with a couple of corrections):

```
var string varchar2(200);

begin
  :string := '<ns1:parent xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/xml" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  ns1:schemaLocation= "http://www.example.com/xml http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns1:child>
      <ns1:values>
        <ns1:value qualifiers="X" date="someTime">Value1</ns1:value>
        <ns1:value qualifiers="X" date="someOtherTime">Value2</ns1:value>
      </ns1:values>
    </ns1:child>
  </ns1:parent>';
end;
/

SELECT myValue, myTime, SYSDATE AS read_date
FROM XMLTable(XMLNamespaces('http://www.example.com/xml' as "ns1"),
  '/ns1:parent/ns1:child/ns1:values/ns1:value'
  passing XMLType(:string)
  columns myValue varchar2(20) path '.',
    myTime varchar2(20) path '@date'
);

MYVALUE              MYTIME               READ_DATE
-------------------- -------------------- ----------
Value1               someTime             2016-07-25
Value2               someOtherTime        2016-07-25
```

You can do the same thing with `insert ... select` using your `myXMLType` variable in the `passing` clause, instead of the `XMLType(:string)`.

[`ExtractValue` is deprecated anyway](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions061.htm), and can only return one node so it would get ORA-19025 if you had the XPath right.

Comment: That worked, but I literally had that same thing when I tried XMLTable, with exception that I did "XMLTable(XMLNamespaces(url_address as "ns1"),
  '/ns1:parent/ns1:child/ns1:values' and put the value path down in the column paths...guess it didn't like that. Thanks!

Comment: @BigEMPin - I think that would have given ORA-19279 if you'd made the path `ns1:value`; and given the same blank results if you'd just used just `value` without the namespace. So I guess you were close *8-)